# Can a DLL access external data structures?

Tags: .net, dll, external

I'd like to use a DLL with a VB.NET application, but I want that DLL to access and modify a data structure (large array) that is part of the .NET application (outside the DLL).  Is there a way to create a DLL that uses an external data structure?

If not, what are the best ways to to get a DLL to interact with VB.NET applications without passing large data structures back and forth?

Comment: Is it a native dll or a .net assembly?

Comment: The DLL would be compiled C code.  However, that DLL wouldn't be shared / reused by any other applications, so it could be part of the .net assembly (if I understand your question correctly).